# Change HTML element attribute in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net

How to change html element attribute in php like in javascript

```
document.getElementbyName('btn').width='300';
```

Comment: It seems you haven't tried anything by yourself. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" name="btn" width="<?php echo "300"; ?>" />
```

Comment: But i want this would be after a button click.
I have a register form in php. When a user click submit button, if username already exist, the username field would be red background.

Comment: @AvijitPalit, well that significantly expands the scope of your question. You can always apply attributes to fields conditionally based on POST data.